# Visual Studio Code regex for (not (xx))

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to have a regex to capture all strings with this shape:

```
(not  (xx))
```

I.e. a parenthesis, a "not", two empty spaces, two caracters between parenthesis and a closing parenthesis

I have tried:

```
(not  (*))
```

But I get:

> Invalid regular expression. Nothing to repeat

[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: You seem to not yet know what regular expressions are. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#writing_a_regular_expression_pattern) for the docs. (Note you don't need the `/ /` in VSCode.) So for your case for example it would be `\(not 
\(.*?\)\)` (however, your screenshot shows only one empty space, not two). Or, if you actually wanted to match exactly two characters in the parentheses, `\(not  \(..\)\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *`Nothing to repeat`* error is due to the `*` quantifier used to quantify an opening bracket of a capturing group construct.

You need to 1) escape special `(` and `)` chars, and 2) match any text between the closest `(` and `)` with a negated character class, here, with `[^()]*`:

```
\(not  \([^()]*\)\)
```

*Details*:

- `\(not  \(` - a `(not  (` string
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)\)`  - a `))` string.

If there can be any zero or more whitespace chars between `not` and `(`, replace the literal spaces with `\s*`. If there must be one or more whitespaces, use `\s+` instead:

```
\(not\s*\([^()]*\)\)
\(not\s+\([^()]*\)\)
```